# `nix profile install` always results in conflict with home-manager

Tags: nix, nix-flake, home-manager

For every package I try to install with nix profile, my home-manager install (with flake) seems to be in the way:

```
❯ hello
The program 'hello' is not in your PATH. It is provided by several packages.
You can make it available in an ephemeral shell by typing one of the following:
  nix-shell -p fltk
  nix-shell -p fltk14
  nix-shell -p haskellPackages.hello
  nix-shell -p hello
  nix-shell -p mbedtls

~ 
❯ nix profile install nixpkgs#hello
error: An existing package already provides the following file:

         /nix/store/gwyaapg12wpj2gd5chyllg3dmrgq811h-home-manager-path/share/bash-completion/completions/home-manager

       This is the conflicting file from the new package:

         /nix/store/kfmgvy3vky5s2jcvn7ih354i11l0asmz-home-manager-2021-03-21/share/bash-completion/completions/home-manager

       To remove the existing package:

         nix profile remove /nix/store/gwyaapg12wpj2gd5chyllg3dmrgq811h-home-manager-path

       The new package can also be installed next to the existing one by assigning a different priority.
       The conflicting packages have a priority of 5.
       To prioritise the new package:

         nix profile install /nix/store/kfmgvy3vky5s2jcvn7ih354i11l0asmz-home-manager-2021-03-21 --priority 4

       To prioritise the existing package:

         nix profile install /nix/store/kfmgvy3vky5s2jcvn7ih354i11l0asmz-home-manager-2021-03-21 --priority 6
```

Comment: Could it be related to https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager/issues/4298 that has been fixed recently? If not you might get more answers in the nixos discourse.

Comment: If you try one of the suggested cmdlines, do you have access to hello in that nix-shell?

The first error, not found in your path, suggests that your current shell/user environment isn't configured to have nix profile binary path (usually ~/.nix-profile/bin ) if your path. Check your environment variables to verify...